# How do I save a file and maybe ask for admin permissions?

Tags: node.js

I am making a game launcher for my games, and I want to be able to download the files from amazon s3, and install them into C:\Program Files directory. How do I do that, and also how do I ask for admin permissions if needed?

Comment: but it wasnt what i was looking for. i think you misunderstood :(

Answer (score 0):

To write a file, you can use the built-in `fs` module.

1. Import the `fs` module.

   ```js
   const fs = require("fs");
   ```
2. Use the `fs.writeFile()` method.

   ```js
   const content = "Content for the program!";

   fs.writeFile('C:\\Program Files\\program.txt', content, (err) => {
     if (err) {
       console.error(err);
       return
     }

     // Code here if successful...
   });
   ```

---

To check if your script is running with admin privileges, you can use the `is-elevated` module on *npm*.

1. Install `is-elevated` from *npm* (ignore the *$*).

   ```
   $ npm install is-elevated
   ```
2. Use the `import` statement to add it in your code.

   ```js
   import isElevated from "is-elevated";
   ```
3. Call the method to see if your script is running with elevated privileges.

   ```js
   console.log(await isElevated());
   ```